# How to make a div act as a scrollbar handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar, navigationbar

I'm trying to make a highly customized 'scrollbar' (more like a navbar that scrolls) for my application, but I can't find any plugins that fit my needs.

**My questions are:**

- What function is being invoked [**here**](http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/) that is making the `window` scroll once the red `div` is translated? (is it `$.scrollTop()`, if so, how do I animate that?)
- Is there an ultimate plugin that I'm not privy to that simplifies *custom navigation of a scrollable element* (meaning [**drag-to-scroll**](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/), [**arrow key**](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/19-keyboard-control.html), and/or [**minimap**](http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/) navigation support, preferably horizontal and vertical w/ momentum/easing + bounce).

I've seen [IScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll), but it's no longer supported as of ~2 years and lacks mouse wheel easing and bounce. Am I missing something? Thanks for the help!

**Edit**: Turns out it is `$.scrollTop` for the first question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, seems like what you were looking for:

http://codepen.io/blyk/pen/JGtfd

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("div").mouseenter(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('active');
   });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't have scroll navigation, it's basically just a tab system.

Comment: You can still remove those anchors whatsoever.